# layout file won't render in IntelliJ designer

Tags: android

I have two screens in an Android app I'm developing with IntelliJ Idea 12.1.  A list screen and an entry/edit screen for a database.  The layout file for the edit screen renders in the IntelliJ designer but the list screen doesn't.

List XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.tjdroid.taskreminder.views.ReminderListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/reminder_list"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/reminder_empty"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/no_reminders"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.tjdroid.taskreminder.views.ReminderListView>
```

Edit XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.tjdroid.taskreminder.views.ReminderEditView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="@string/title"/>
        <EditText android:id="@+id/title"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/confirm"
                android:text="@string/confirm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.tjdroid.taskreminder.views.ReminderEditView>
```

Render error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Cannot perform rendering
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.configureError(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:543)
    at com.intellij.designer.designSurface.DesignerEditorPanel.showError(DesignerEditorPanel.java:404)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$8$3.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:417)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:343)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:691)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:686)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:511)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:334)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderUtil.renderLayout(RenderUtil.java:195)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$8.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:346)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong in the list screen?

Thanks

Comment: IDEA shows a warning in the preview window.  If you click it, it will tell you why it can't render.  Your custom EditView is my guess.  You need to code it so that it can render at compile time.  If you rely on external classes and/or resources which are not available at compile time, you can use `isInEditMode()` to use code which will run at compile time.  The IDEA logs also contain a detailed stack trace of the error preventing rendering from completing.

Comment: And it does but I'm not nearly experienced enough to understand what it's trying to tell me.  I added the Render error message to the original post.

Comment: Did you get the stack trace from the log or from the warning?

Comment: I got it from the warning